# Where vs ON in outer join

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I am wondering how to have a better SQL performance when we decide whether to duplicate our criteria  when it is already in Where clause.

My friend claimed it is up to DB engines but I am not so sure.

Regardless of DB engines, normally, the condition in Where clause should be executed first before join, but I assume it means inner join but not outer join. Because some conditions can only be executed AFTER outer join.

For example:

```
Select a.*, b.* 
From A a
Left outer join B on a.id = b.id 
Where b.id is NULL;
```

The condition in Where cannot be executed before outer join.

So, I assume the whole ON clause must be executed first before where clause, and it seems the ON clause will control the size of table B (or table A if we use right outer join) before outer join. That seems not related to DB engines to me.

And that raised my question: when we use outer join, should we always deplicate our criteria in ON Clause?

for example (I use a table to outer join with a shorter version of itself)

**temp_series_installment & series_id > 18940000**   vs   **temp_series_installment**:

```
select sql_no_cache s.*, t.* from temp_series_installment s
left outer join temp_series_installment t on s.series_id = t.series_id and t.series_id > 18940000 and t.incomplete = 1
where t.incomplete = 1;
```

VS

```
select sql_no_cache s.*, t.* from temp_series_installment s
left outer join temp_series_installment t on s.series_id = t.series_id and t.series_id > 18940000
where t.incomplete = 1;
```

**Edit**: where t.incomplete = 1 performs the logic of: where t.series_id is not null
which is an inner join suggested by Gordon Linoff
But what I have been asking is: if it outer join a smaller table, it should have been faster right?

I tried to see if there is any performace difference in mysql:

[image]

But it is out of my expectation, why is the second one faster? I thought by outer joining a smaller table, the query will be faster.

My idea is from:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/refs/rsdperformanceworkspaces.htm

Section:

Push predicates into the OUTER JOIN clause whenever possible
Duplicate constant condition for different tables whenever possible

Comment: Your examples with `where` turn the outer join into an inner join.  Hence, your question does not make sense.

Comment: you are right but it still does not explain why the performance downgraded. Given that it should have outer joined a smaller dataset

Comment: How much faster is it? and is it consistent? I don't know what units those screenshots but percentagewise those times are basically the same. `19:17:44` vs `19:17:50`. If those are not timings, please actually post some timings (that you've tested and averaged three or four times)

Comment: Hmm... sorry I forgot not everyone used workbench. The last column in that photo is Duration / Fetch

Comment: As my trails are all stating the second being faster, I did not bother putting more tests. My bad. Image updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gordon Lindolf pointed out it's not true, Your friend is plain wrong.

I want just to add developers like to think SQL like they think their language of trade (C++, VB, Java), but those are procedural/imperative languages.
When you code SQL you are in another paradigm. You are just describing a function to be applied to a dataset.

Let's get your own example:

```
Select a.*, b.* 
From A a
Left outer join B on a.id = b.id 
Where b.id is NULL;
```

*If `a.Id` and `b.Id` are not null columns.*

It's semantically equal to

```
Select a.*, null, ..., null
From A a
where not exists (select * from B b where b.Id = a.Id)
```

Now try to run those to queries and profile.
In most DBMS I can expect both queries to run in the exact same way.

It happens because the engine decides how to implement your "function" over the dataset.

Note the above example is the equivalent in set mathematics to:

> Give me the set A minus the intersection between A and B.

Engines can decide how to implement your query because they have some tricks under its sleeve.
It has metrics about your tables, indexes, etc and can use it to, for example, "make a join" in a diferent order you wrote it.

IMHO engines today are really good at finding the best way to implement the function you describe and rarely needs query hints.
Of course you can end describing your funciton in a way too complicated, affecting how the engines decides to run it.
The art of better describing functions and sets and managins indexes is what we call query tunning.

Answer (score 4):

> Regardless of DB engines, normally, the condition in Where clause should be executed first before join, but I assume it means inner join but not outer join. Because some conditions can only be executed AFTER outer join.

This is simply not true.  SQL is a *descriptive* language.  *It does not specify how the query gets executed.*  It only specifies what the result set looks like.  The SQL compiler/optimizer determines the actual processing steps to meet the requirements described by the query.

In terms of semantics, the `FROM` clause is the first clause that is "evaluated".  Hence, `FROM` is logically processed *before* the `WHERE` clause.

The rest of your question is similarly misguided.  Comparison logic in the `where` clause, such as:

```
from s left join
     t
    on s.series_id = t.series_id and t.series_id > 18940000
where t.incomplete = 1
```

turns the outer join into an inner join.  Hence, the logic is different from what you think is going on.

Comment: I see. Thanks I do learn something from your answer and comment. But for the reason I mentioned from my first comment, I would upvote your answer but not marked as answered, at least not yet